# Why does Chrome triggers focus instead of visibilitychange when changing tabs not in focus?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check for page visibility change, but there is a case where `focus` event is triggered instead of `visibilitychange`.

I am using Chrome.

To reproduce this scenario, you need to open another window side by side to this window with the snippet, for example I open the devtools and place them on each half of the screen.

Then, while I'm on the snippet window, I click somewhere in the devtools window, and then I click on a new tab or an existing tab on the window with the snippet.

Then, the `event.type` in the log is `focus`. I think it might be because for a split moment, if you moved to another window while not in focus on the current window, then before switching tabs, it "focuses" the window and then switch tabs.

I am not listening to the `blur` event at all, so it's not triggered but I assume it will also be triggered if I had listened, however I don't need it. What I need is to know when the page was hidden.

Also, I added a `setTimeout` for cases where multiple events can be triggered at once, so it's also weird that it prefers to catch the `focus` event (Which is not even real `focus`), and not the `visibilitychange` event.

The snippet:

```js
let eventCanTrigger = true;
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", (event) => {
  logEvent(event);
});

window.addEventListener('focus', (event) => {
  logEvent(event);
});

function logEvent(event) {
  if (eventCanTrigger) {
    console.log("event type from logEvent: " + event.type);
    eventCanTrigger = false;
    setTimeout(() => {
      eventCanTrigger = true;
    }, 100);
  }
}
```

Why does it do it?